# Are there any more polytopes whose 2-faces are identical 4-gons?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, polytopes

What are examples for *convex* polytope $P\subset \Bbb R^d,d\ge 3$ for which holds

- $P$ is 2-face transitive (that is, all 2-faces are equivalent under the symmetries of $P$), and
- all 2-faces of $P$ are 4-gons (not necessarily squares, or rectangles).

I know the $d$-cubes, rhombic dodecahedron and rhombic triacontahedron. Are there any others?

I expect other such a polytope, if at all, then only in $d\ge 4$. Maybe a slight modification of a *neighborly cubical polytope* as constructed by Ziegler [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9812033), but as they are, they have two 2-face orbits.

Comment: Rhombic dodecahedron?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov You are absolutely right. And also the rhombic triacontahedron. I have overlooked these. So I guess my question now is whether there are any more?

Comment: What about Cartesian products of $d$-cubes, rhombic dodecahedrons and rhombic triacontahedrons?

Comment: @Bullet51 I think the cartesian product of a $d_1$-cube and a $d_2$-cube is a $(d_1+d_2)$-cube. You are right about the latter two examples. I already mentioned these in my comment, but I should edit them into my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, there are many to be found on Wikipedia under [isogonal figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isohedral_figure), even in three dimensions.

Examples in dimension *four* are obtained as dual polytope of [runcinated 4-simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runcinated_5-cell#Runcinated_5-cell) or [runcinated 24-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runcinated_24-cells). This works, because these both runcinations are

1. edge-transitive, and
2. each edge is contained in exactly four facets.

Since in the dual edges become 2-faces and facets become vertices, the resulting dual polytopes will be 2-face-transitive, and each 2-face will have four vertices, that is, they will be 4-gons.

If I am not mistaken, the cells of these two examples are [trigonal trapezohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonal_trapezohedron) (aka. elongated cubes), and these are 3-dimensional examples also found in the Wikipedia list mentioned above.